# limit value of $\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{-1/x} = 0 $ , want to know why this is true

Tags: real-analysis

I have a quick question

why

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{-1/x} =  0 ??$$

I thought if $x$ is approaching $0$ the value should be nearby $e^{-1}$. Why this result is end with $0$??

Comment: Why should it be nearly $e^{-1}$? Remember that $1/x\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Putting $\;y:=\frac1x\;$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{-1/x}=\lim_{y\to\infty}e^{-y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac1{e^y}\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

That is equivalent to

$$1 / e^{1/x}$$

The closer $x$ gets to $0$ the bigger $1/x$ gets, the bigger $1/x$ gets, the bigger $e$ gets, the bigger $e$ gets, the closer $1/e^{1/x}$ gets to $0$.

Comment: You really should try to type mathematics with LaTeX, as most member of the site do. That way your questions/answers will look much nicer and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It is $-\frac{1}{x}$ not $x$ so when $x$ is very small positive number then $-\frac{1}{x}$ is a very large negative number . If a number greater than $1$ is raised to a very large negative number then it will be very close to $0$