# What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^\frac{1}{x}$?

I have found similar problems, but not quite this one.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts at all?

Comment: I would start by computing $\lim _{x\to\infty}\frac 1x$

Comment: Have you found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602398/limit-value-of-e-1-x-0-want-to-know-why-this-is-true/602402)?

Comment: Do you know that $e^0=1$?

Comment: It's 1 bro as @Salahamam_Fatima said.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{(1/x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{(1/\text{a really big number})}=\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{(0)}=1$$

Notice that $\dfrac{1}{1000000000000000}\approx0$

Also by definition, $b^0=1,b\in\mathbb{R},b\neq0$

Comment: $b^0=1, b\in \mathbb{R}$, and $b\neq{0}.$

Comment: thank you I will add that in

Comment: That intermediate part about a big number is what you must avoid. From mathematical point of view it is nonsense. Just note that $\lim_{x\to\infty} 1/x=0$ and $e^{x} $ is continuous at $x=0$ so that $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{1/x}=e^0=1$.

Comment: It is not nonsense. It helps the OP understand WHY its $0$.

Comment: Just to let you know $\infty$ as used in this context does not mean "a really big number". Such explanations only add to confusion and you should rather explain the actual meaning of symbol $\infty$ used here.

Answer (score 2):

Here some facts.

1) Consider the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Its limit for $x \to +\infty$ is:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = 0.$$

2) The function $f(y) = e^y$ is continuous in $y = 0$.

---

Your limit can be rewritten has:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(g(x)).$$

For the facts 1) and 2) enlisted above, you can do the following:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(g(x)) = f\left(\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)\right).$$

In other words, the limit of the composition of two function $f$ and $g$ can be found as the first function evaluated in the limit of the second function, under the hypothesis that the limit of $g$ is exists and the $f$ is continuous in that point (in this case, the limit of $g$ is $0$ and $f$ is continuous in $0$).

Concluding:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^{\left(\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{1}{x}\right)} = e^0 = 1.$$

---

In a similar way, you can find the limits of composed functions such as $$\sin\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right), \log\left(\frac{3x^2-1}{x^2+x}\right), \cos\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\ldots$$

Comment: While this answer is obviously correct, I think it is a bit out of proportion with the question. If someone is having a hard time finding the limit of $e^x$, they probably won't be helped by something as formal as this.

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard Maybe you are right. Anyway, the OP said "I have found similar problems, but not quite this one.". Then, I argued that he/she is not a complete newbie to the world of limits and continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

As x approaches infinity, 1/x approaches 0.  (i.e., lim (1/x) = 0 )

So exp(1/x) will approach exp(0) = 1

If you graph exp(1/x), you will see that the horizontal assymptote (as x grows very large) is 1.0

Comment: Good answer, but I advise the use of mathjax on this site.

Comment: yes please use that

Answer (score 0):

let:
$$
u=1/x\\
$$
as:
$$
x \to \infty \\
1/x \to 0
$$
or
$$
u \to 0
$$
and you got:
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{1/x}=\lim_{u\to 0}e^u=1
$$